# horizontal scroll bar issue in production environment in mobile

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i have created  a responsive page with bootstrap 3. I am having a problem in all mobile devices, there is long scroll bar coming. Strange thing is it is coming fine in my local machine. Issue is only reproducible in production environment. I have tried every thing but nothing worked.

Using meta tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

This issue is making me insane, i am not getting the cause of this issue.

Below is the page url
http://beta.proptiger-ws.com/careers

[image]

Even if i remove the entire body tag in consle panel the scroll bar still comes. Let me know if you guys need any other detail.

I am updating this question my new finding are this page is not becoming responsive thats why the scrollbar is coming. dont know what is wrong with the viewport meta as same page working fine on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

That site is not responsive if you have set widths

Search for the class below and change.

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) and (max-width: 768px)
.mainContainer, .footer-container, .footer-cont-info, .copy-container, .searchFilter {
width: 100%;
}
```

Be sure to do a hard refresh when editing in external css files (ctrl + F5)

Comment: I have overridden that width with below css:

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) { 
  .mainContainer { width: 100% !important; }

Comment: you will need to overwrite all I think

 .mainContainer, .footer-container, .footer-cont-info, .copy-container, .searchFilter

Comment: other classes are not getting use in the page. Strange thing is page in working fine in my local machine but not on production environment.

Comment: As Gezzasa says, you will need to override the others (with !important) if `.mainContainer` is nested inside one of these. You may need to check which style appears last in the production CSS. But this is a classic example of why `!important` should not be used or at least avoided as best as possible, simply as it breaks the point of cascading styles in well thought out CSS!

Comment: If you can, remove the '!important' and list the style at the bottom of the stylesheet. It will take priority if it is at the bottom.

Also, you have a wrapping container with the width on too.

<div data-ng-class="{'fitMainContainer' : fitPageView, 'addSearchContainer' : addPageSearch}" class="mainContainer row-fluid">

Comment: Did the suggested changes but didn't worked. Can check the provided url

Comment: @Gezzasa As suggested i updated my code but still getting the issue. I noticed the issue is not with the scrollbar but page is not becoming responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Check the css for **min-width**.

If there is any element with min-width greater than the page then it would produce a scrollbar.

Comment: There is no element with min-width. i've used width in % and max-width.

Comment: The navbar you made is not re-sizing for smaller width. In chrome or firefox open screen size simulator and try to reduce the width slowly. You will see that your nav bar will get stuck at a specific point and will be producing the scrollbar.

Comment: nice point, but i have removed the entire header section in console panel of simulator but the issue still comes. I cant do the real changes in files as i dont have the authority to deploy the files in production so trying to fix in debugger panel

Comment: I will try to debug it and provide you with an answer later on.